# How to refresh kendo-textbox-container in custom component (commercial Kendo-UI for Angular components)

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I created my own input component which wraps `kendo-textbox-container`.
I am having problems, that `floatingLabel` is not correctly rendered if initial value is set.

[image: screenshot]

Here is [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/elUcIAwu57KPc2r8E1KA?p=preview).

I thought that

```
this.input.nativeElement.blur();
```

will force kendo to re-render but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug and it is reported [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1708).